# Express + Node 18 + TypeScript - dev server won't run

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Problem:

- When I run this command: `npx ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only index.ts`, I get this error:

```
rob@hi~/dev/robrendellwebsite$ npx ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only index.ts
[INFO] 06:23:55 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 4.8.4)
Compilation error in /home/rob/dev/robrendellwebsite/index.ts
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/rob/dev/robrendellwebsite/index.ts
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rob/dev/robrendellwebsite/index.ts:1:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._compile (/home/rob/dev/robrendellwebsite/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-6490566241511986.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-6490566241511986.js:114:20)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-6490566241511986.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/home/rob/dev/robrendellwebsite/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
[ERROR] 06:23:55 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/rob/dev/robrendellwebsite/index.ts
```

What I've tried:

- adding "type":"module" to my package.json:

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "robrendellwebsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "nodejs backend api for robrendellwebsite",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "dev:slow": "ts-node index.ts",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --pretty --transpile-only index.ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .ts --fix",
    "update-common": "npm install robrendellwebsite-common"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Robert-Rendell/robrendellwebsite.git"
  },
  "author": "Robert Rendell",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Robert-Rendell/robrendellwebsite/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Robert-Rendell/robrendellwebsite#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/morgan": "~1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.8",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.2.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "googleapis": "^108.0.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1243.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.6.0",
    "helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.10.0",
    "robrendellwebsite-common": "^1.2.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

Here's my index.ts:

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import { HomePage } from './src/pages/home/home.page';
import SudokuAPI from './src/pages/sudoku/sudoku.page';
import TechTestUniDataAPI from './src/pages/technical-tests/uni-data-291121/uni-data-291121.page';
import { NatureRouting } from './src/pages/photos-ive-taken/nature/nature.routing';
import { WildFlowersPage } from './src/pages/photos-ive-taken/nature/pages/wild-flowers.page';
import { ArachnidsPage } from './src/pages/photos-ive-taken/nature/pages/arachnids.page';
import { InsectsPage } from './src/pages/photos-ive-taken/nature/pages/insects.page';
import { LichenPage } from './src/pages/photos-ive-taken/nature/pages/lichen.page';
import { FungiPage } from './src/pages/photos-ive-taken/nature/pages/fungi.page';

config();

if (!process.env.PORT) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// Heroku exposes PORT env var by default
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

const app = express();
// app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(express.json());
// === Rate Limiting =======================
// only if you're behind a reverse proxy
// eg. (Heroku, Bluemix, AWS if you use an ELB, custom Nginx setup, etc)
app.enable('trust proxy');
// const limiter = RateLimit({
//   windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
//   max: 100, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
// });

// apply to all requests
//app.use(limiter);
// =========================================

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

// === Routes =========================================
app.get('/', HomePage);

app.get('/', HomePage);

app.get(NatureRouting.WildFlowers, WildFlowersPage);
app.get(NatureRouting.Arachnids, ArachnidsPage);
app.get(NatureRouting.Insects, InsectsPage);
app.get(NatureRouting.Lichen, LichenPage);
app.get(NatureRouting.Fungi, FungiPage);

app.get(SudokuAPI.Routes.getSudoku, SudokuAPI.getSudoku);
app.get(SudokuAPI.Routes.getSudokuLeaderboard, SudokuAPI.getSudokuLeaderboard);
app.post(SudokuAPI.Routes.postSudokuList, SudokuAPI.postSudokuList);
app.post(SudokuAPI.Routes.postSubmission, SudokuAPI.postSubmission);
app.post(SudokuAPI.Routes.postGenerateSudoku, SudokuAPI.generateSudoku);
app.post(SudokuAPI.Routes.postGenerateSudokuCallback, SudokuAPI.generateSudokuCallback);

app.get(TechTestUniDataAPI.Routes.getDashboardGraphs, TechTestUniDataAPI.getDashboardGraphs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in my case was to do with a dependency:  "robrendellwebsite-common": "^1.2.0", which wasn't configured correctly and caused transpiled JavaScript to be different to the project that imported it. Didn't get to the root cause exactly, but the answer in this case was to rollback. This is a lesson in committing small changes at a time so you can easily isolate where you went wrong.